# TypeScript: Declaring a type of array of types

Tags: typescript

Running into a TypeScript issue trying to create a type that consists of an array of other types.

```js
export interface Dog {
  woof: boolean;
}

export interface Cat {
  meow: boolean;
}

export type Animal = (Dog | Cat)[]; // something wrong here?
```

```js
let animals: Animal[] = [];

let dog: Dog = { woof: true };

animals.push(dog); // raises an error
```

The error is:

Argument of type 'Dog' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Animal'. Type 'Dog' is missing the following properties from type '(Dog | Cat)[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, the declaration for Animal needs to be changed to:

```js
export type Animal = Dog | Cat;
```

Comment: Yep! the issue in your original post was that `Animal` was already an array type, so `Animal[]` was actually an array of arrays of cats or dogs.